# What could override group permissions on a linux directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

I am logged in as user1, and grp1 is one of my secondary groups.  So why would I not be able to access a folder on which grp1 has read permissions?

```
    [user1@machine ~]$ groups user1
    user1 : user1 users grp1
    [user1@machine ~]$ sudo ls -ld /etc/httpd/logs
    drwxr-x--- 4 root grp1 4096 Sep 11 03:59 /etc/httpd/logs
    [user1@machine ~]$ ls /etc/httpd/logs
    ls: /etc/httpd/logs: Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you have read and exec permissions on both /etc and /etc/httpd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether you are *currently* in that group by running `id` - if you haven't logged in (or su'ed) since adding that group membership, you won't have it yet.

Comment: The problem was exactly what you said.  I su'd and then I was in the group.  That did it --- Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this - you just saved me from asking an otherwise stupid question!

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have read permission to parent DIR

Answer (score 0):

You can set the group before writing a file shared with grp1:
    newgrp grp1